# Is there a way to save multiple embedded models in db at once using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions, sequelize.js

Suppose we have a such structure in NodeJs [Sequelize](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/).

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {/* ... */})
var Project = sequelize.define('project', {/* ... */})

Project.hasMany(User)
```

In [this part of video](https://youtu.be/53bdrz7cZ-c?t=13m10s) presenter offers to save embedded objects with two steps using promises. In our case it would be something like:

```
Project.create({
  ...
  }).then(function(project){
     User.create({
        ...
        projectId:project.id
     })
   })
```

But this approach will result **two** db calls.

So, is it possible to save embedded objects (Project which contains User e.g. User must have Project's id as a foreign key) into the db with one db call or within a transaction using Sequelize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to insert parent-children by passing an array of objects into a key with the same name as the `"as"` value used on the `"include"`. Although the [documentation is light](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/api/model/#createvalues-options-promiseinstance) on the usage, you can see it handled in the [source code here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/instance.js#L700).

No promises (pun semi-intended) that this is *actually* run in single SQL query, not sure of the exact implementation in Sequelize. You should be able to enable logging (`logging: console.log` in the `Sequelize(options)`) to see what it's running.

```js
// specify an "as" value and require a User.project_id value
Project.hasMany(User, { as: 'Users', foreignKey: { allowNull: false } });

// define your Project -> Users as json with the "as" value as the key
const project = {
  name: 'project name',
  Users: [
    {
      name: 'user 1',
    },
    {
      name: 'user 2',
    },
  ],
};

// create a transaction and "include" the Model in the create, txn falls back in .catch()
sequelize.transaction(t => 
  Project.create(project, {
    include: [{
      model: User,
      as: 'Users',
    }],
    transaction: t,
  })
)
.catch(e => console.log('the txn failed because', e));
```

Comment: Thank You for the response). 
It saves all data as expected, but log shows several "Executing" lines with the same key:
    `Executing (some_key): START TRANSACTION;
    Executing (the_same_key): SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
    Executing (the_same-Key): INSERT INTO "user" ... RETURNING *;
    Executing (the_same-Key): ...other inserts...
    Executing (the_same-Key): COMMIT;`

Dose the same key show that everything happens in one query?

Comment: I doubt it, that's usually part of the trade-off with using an ORM.

Comment: And to clarify, by wrapping it in a transaction if any of the INSERTS fail, they will all be rolled back. It's also possible that multiple queries are sent to the server at one time rather than a back and forth, but performance wise I think it's negligible.

Comment: Ok, understand. I can not upwote your answer because of my reputation, but I'll mark it as answered.